# Delete an IP address to the loopback interface on netplan

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server, netplan

I needed to add a new IP to the loopback interface (besides the usual localhost 127.0.0.1)

On my Ubuntu server running Netplan I've added on the .yaml file the code

```
lo:
    addresses: [50.1.0.1/16]
```

I applied and everything was cool. The issue came after I wanted to change the IP address; so I edited the file with the new IP for the loopback interface:

```
lo:
    addresses: [10.1.0.1/16]
```

and now, after having applied, I have both IPs.

How can I delete the previews IP and how can I rewrite the configuration instead of adding IPs every time I want to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
ethernets:
        lo:
            match:
                name: lo
            addresses: [ 10.1.0.1/16 ]
```

instead.

It should keep just the IP you want